# WordPress Sage 9 - get dist url?

Tags: php, wordpress, roots-sage

I'm trying to make the move to Sage 9 as a starter template, however when I try use `get_template_directory_uri()` I get a return from within the /resources directory.

Unfortunately the assets I want are in the dist folder, a sibling of resources (as per Sage 9's documentation)

I'm using @asset which works fine inside a blade, but I cannot access that from within another php file.

In Sage 8 and vanilla WordPress this was always the method I used to access my theme URI.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with this?

Thanks

Comment: Does `\App\asset_path` made what you needed in the end ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use asset() helper equivalent in other WP PHP files like so:

```
\App\asset_path('your_folder/file_from_dist.ext');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `get_theme_file_uri()` and that will give you the URL to the theme folder.

In my demo `get_template_directory_uri()` returns `http://sage.test/wp-content/themes/sage-demo` while `get_template_directory_uri()` returns `http://sage.test/wp-content/themes/sage-demo/resources`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That's actually exactly what I've done, but it feels more of a workaround than the solution. It seems strange that they would intentionally change how a default, highly used, WordPress function works :-/